# How can I pull the Authors name from a file?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the author of a PDF document.

I've tried things like getOwner() but that returns the account of the computer the file is on, not the actual author.

```
PosixFileAttributes otherLeafInfo = Files.readAttributes(nodeMetaData, PosixFileAttributes.class);
fileAuthor.setText("Author: "+ otherLeafInfo.owner().getName());
```

This shows my accounts name, not the actual file author.

Can anyone help extract the actual author info?

It exists, at least in a Mac environment because get info shows the correct author.

Comment: You should probably try some type of `PDF` handling `API`.

Comment: [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) <- Good place to start.

Comment: Because you say that the Mac can display the information you want, it might not be necessary to read and parse the whole PDF document.  The Mac may already have this data extracted and stored somewhere.  I don't, however, know how you can get to that info.  It may be that using PDFBox, or something similar, IS the right way to go.  I just wanted to point out this alternative approach.

Comment: Of course, if you want your code to be cross-platform, getting the info from the Mac environment isn't the way to go. - if you don't care about other platforms, then you might want to try to get the information you want to show up at a command prompt, in response to running some command.  If you could do this, then you could use one of the Java APIs that let you run external commands to get at this data by running the same command you ran at the command prompt.

Comment: Made this an "answer", but then backed off.  You probably want a native Java solution to this.  But just so you know...I found and installed **exiftool** using **brew**.  The command: `exiftool testfile.pdf | grep Author` gave me a single line of output containing the PDF's author.  Note that although this isn't a pure Java solution, and so maybe isn't the best option anyway, it might be cross platform as that doesn't sound like a Mac-only sort of tool.

Comment: Note that **exiftool** can read metadata from a Huge number of file formats. - and it does appear to be fully cross platform.  Unfortunately, it's written in Perl, not Java.

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply. I've gone with the PDFBox Sedrick responded with, but yes I would like a purely java native solution. This will work for now however, thanks!